# JUnit: Running @Before-method when using Categories

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

**Edit:**
Background: We are building an application that is storing customer preferences of a set of categories.

Use cases are of the type that if you have no preference set of type X1 you should not be able to create a preference X2. X3 should never be created, but you should be able to ask the system for it.

What I want to do is to run a certain group of tests for each preference combination a customer can have to make sure we aren't doing stupid changes and breaking any business rules.

If I write each test in a test class for a certain preference combination, I have identified I need to write 64 tests. But it is more or less just 16 test in total that I can repeat over and over again.

customerCanCreatePreferenceX
customerCanCreatePreferenceX

**Implementation:**
I have written a set of test cases that I want to execute.

I have annotated each test with @Category, and grouped the tests this way.

To run my tests I have created a test suite that is run with the Categories-runner.

I would like to create a test suite for each Category-group and somehow reset the context to a certain state before each test is executed.

Is that possible? How?

**Note:** I have tried to use @Before in the test suite, but that isn't being executed by the runner. It seems as if Categories ignores the @Before-annotation or only run those in the tested class, AllTests

I have also tried using @Rule on a TestRule, but this shows the same behavior as @Before.

I have spent 8hrs or so googling, reading documentations and watching youtube tutorials, but I still haven't been able to solve this issue.

Perhaps the way I am creating the tests is all wrong? Perhaps I should use Parameterized tests instead in some smart way?

**Example code:**

```
public class AllTests {
    @Test
    @Category({GroupA.class, GroupB.class})
    public void testCase1(){
        //Some test code
    }

    @Test
    @Category({GroupA.class})
    public void testCase2(){
        //Some test code
    }
}

@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory({GroupA.class})
@SuiteClasses({AllTests.class})
public class GroupATestSuite{ 
    // How to create context for GroupA-tests
}

@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory({GroupB.class})
@SuiteClasses({AllTests.class})
public class GroupBTestSuite{ 
    // How to create context for GroupB-tests
}
```

Comment: You have explained the implementation, but it doesn't contain why you wanted to do this way and the underlying requirement.

Comment: @notionquest Thanks, I've edited the question adding some more background.